# How to distinguish a button and a checkbox message on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, wxwidgets

I have the Windows event values that for example the `DefWindowsProc()` gets -- i.e. `hWnd, MsgId, wParam, lParam`. **Is it possible to distinguish** whether the `WM_COMMAND` event with notification code `BN_CLICKED` comes or from **a push button**, or **from a check box** (or possibly from some other)?

**Motivation:** I am rewriting the GUI implementation and message handling in a bigger application.  The final goal is wxWidgets, but I have to do it gradually.  I do mimick the `BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE`/`END_EVENT_TABLE` macros and the related `EVT_BUTTON`, `EVT_CHECKBOX` (..., `EVT_SIZE`, `EVT_PAINT` and the like).  I am also mimicking classes like `wxCommandEvent`, and I would like to set its type to the equivalent of `wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED` or `wxEVT_COMMAND_CHECKBOX_CLICKED` when the event is captured by the original code.

**For example:**  I have a macro like this

```
#define EVT_CHECKBOX(id, func) \
    if (uMsg == WM_COMMAND && id == LOWORD(wParam)) \
    { \
        CAppCommandEvent evt(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); \
        ATLASSERT(evt.GetEventType() == appEVT_COMMAND_CHECKBOX_CLICKED); \
        func(evt); \
        lResult = evt.GetLResult(); \
        if (!evt.GetSkipped()) \
            return TRUE; \
    }
```

The `wxEVT_COMMAND_CHECKBOX_CLICKED` is intentionally renamed to `appEVT_...`.  I want to be able to check whether the `EVT_CHECKBOX` macro was not used (by mistake) for a button.  If yes, the assert command must make it visible for the debug version of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in the message itself can serve you to identify the type of button. However, in theory you should still be able to find it out indirectly. The `lParam` gives you the window handle of the control, which you can use with `GetWindowLong` to obtain the [button style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
LONG style = ::GetWindowLong(lParam, GWL_STYLE);
if (style & BS_CHECKBOX) {
    // It's a checkbox
}
```

Comment: I think we have a winner here. Good thinking on that one.

Comment: I don't have a test set up handy to confirm it works, though. That's why I said in theory. So, bear that in mind.

Comment: The only thing I have to say is that `GetWindowLong` is deprecated in way of `GetWindowLongPtr` in x64 or something. It's at the top of the article.

Comment: @irobot: Unfortunately, it does not work.  Both `GetWindowLong()` and `GetWindowLongPtr()` return a window style composed of WS_xxx bits (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  For example, it returns `0x14cc0000` for both push buttons and check boxes in my case.  Any other idea?

Comment: @pepr This is odd. I just tried it and it seems to work for me. The `BS_xxx` styles are, as far as I can tell, a subset of the `WS_xxx` styles. Are you sure you are using the right handle with `GetWindowLongPtr`? What does the section of the resource file that defines the buttons look like? Try looking at the window styles of these buttons with Spy++ or similar.

Comment: @irobot: Stupid me!  You are right.  I was passing the parent `hWnd` instead of the `lParam`.  The only detail is that the `lParam` must be converted to `HWND` type.  Another detail is tha the test must not be done like `if (style & BS_PUSHBUTTON)` as this constant is zero. (The Spy++ helped ;)

Comment: @pepr True. I only used `&` because it works for both `BS_CHECKBOX` and `BS_AUTOCHECKBOX`. I should have been more explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

" rewriting the GUI implementation and message handling in a bigger application. The final goal is wxWidgets, but I have to do it gradually."

Really?  IMHO you are mad.  It would be far easier and quicker and infinitely less buggy to rewrite your application to use wxWidgets, rather than use some strange half wxWidgets, half native windows API that you created yourself on the fly.  The only advantage I can see would be job security since no-one else will be able to maintain this monster you are creating.

However, to answer your question:  wxWidgets distinguishes between these two events.  wxEVT_COMMAND_CHECKBOX_CLICKED is generated by a checkbox, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED is generated by a button.  The wxWidgets code is open and very well documented, so take a look and see how they do it.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems you are very fast to judge.  Would you try to rewrite everything with a 250+ k lines of code with a home-made dynamic layout management?  First, I need to make it as similar to wxWidgets as possible.  I did look inside the wxWidget sources, indeed.  If you show me source file and the lines that solve the problem for Windows, I will upvote this comment.

Comment: Yes, I would.  There are 2 possibilities.  You code-base is properly organized and only the small part implementing the GUI needs to be rewritten, so the merest fraction needs rewriting.  Or your code is so badly organized that the GUI implementation is sprinkled throughout the 250K which therefore badly need to be rewritten to fix a horrible mess.

Comment: We can discuss it elsewhere.  But did you consider the possibility that the case is somewhere in between, and that there is more than a fraction of the GUI that must be rewritten?  Frankly, I would not like to follow the case of the Netscape Navigator that was burried by the decision to rewrite it completely.